# How do I combine multiple files in a directory in linux such that each files data is placed in a new column?

Tags: linux, terminal

I have 100 files in a directory, with each file containing a single column of 1000 rows of numbers. I want to combine all these files into a single file resulting in 1000 by 100 data frame with each columns name to be the file name. Is there a way to do this in linux (terminal)?

Comment: Use the `paste` command. It's like `cat` but sideways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with little perl script:

merge.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @lines;
for my $file (@ARGV) {
    open(FI,$file) or die;
    my $i=0;
    while(<FI>) {
        chop;
        $lines[$i].="," if $lines[$i];
        $lines[$i].=$_;
        $i++;
    }
    close(FI);
}

for my $line (@lines) {
    print $line."\n";
}
```

Run it with all file names that you need to merge:

```
./merge.pl dir/*
```